# Wanderlust -- how to grep the contents of thousands of emails

Tags: wanderlust

**Q**:  How can I `grep` thousands of emails within Wanderlust while avoiding the dreaded error of "**Too many arguments**" or finding zero matches (when there should be one or more)?

Wanderlust (and related `elmo` libraries) support searching the contents of emails by using `grep`:  http://wanderlust.github.io/wl-docs/wl.html#grep .  This works well for a small number of emails in the directory to be searched, but does not work when there are thousands of files in the directory -- i.e., zero results are returned even though there should have been one or more hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitation of the number of files is due to the number of arguments `grep` can accept before throwing an error of "**Too many arguments**".  Wanderlust and `elmo` related libraries are filled with `condition-case` statements that mask errors and make troubleshooting extremely time consuming.  The default configuration for `grep` uses the function `elmo-search-grep-target`, which creates a listing of files -- sometimes too many.  In researching this answer, I found it helpful to inspect the functions `elmo-search-engine-do-search` and `elmo-map-folder-list-message-locations`, the latter of which when supplied with a handy `(message ...)` told me that the problem was due to "**Too many arguments**".  This error message led me to an answer by `Barmar` suggesting to use the recursive grep feature and supply a directory, rather than a zillion files.  [ https://stackoverflow.com/a/29727258/2112489 ]  The upshot is that I had also been wanting to enable recursive grepping, which the default configuration did not provide.  So, we create a new function called `elmo-search-rgrep-target` and add the `r` argument to the `grep` search.  The method of searching is essentially the same, from with the Summary or Folder buffer, type the letter "g" and then enter into the minibuffer something like `[hello-world]/path/to/be/recursively/searched!grep`

```lisp
(defun elmo-search-rgrep-target (engine pattern)
  (let ((dirname (expand-file-name (elmo-search-engine-param-internal engine))))
    dirname))

;;; Setup `elmo-search-engine-alist'
(unless noninteractive
  (or (assq 'namazu elmo-search-engine-alist)
      (elmo-search-register-engine
        'namazu 'local-file
        :prog "namazu"
        :args '("--all" "--list" "--early" pattern elmo-search-namazu-index)
        :charset 'iso-2022-jp))
  (or (assq 'mu elmo-search-engine-alist)
      (elmo-search-register-engine
       'mu 'local-file
       :prog "/path/to/executable/mu"
       :args '("find" pattern "--fields" "l" "--muhome=/path/to/muhome/.mu")
       :charset 'utf-8))
  (or (assq 'grep elmo-search-engine-alist)
      (elmo-search-register-engine
       'grep 'local-file
       :prog "grep"
       ;; :args '("-l" "-e" pattern elmo-search-grep-target)
       :args '("-rle" pattern elmo-search-rgrep-target))))
```

---

I've opened up an issue on Github for Wanderlust, but am unsure whether anyone would be interested in this solution given that it could be viewed as relating more to the `elmo` related libraries.  https://github.com/wanderlust/wanderlust/issues/140